# Change colors of table row if column contains certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-selectors

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <div id="divTable" class="divTable">
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>                        
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myContent">
        <tr>
            <td>Some Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="findMe">
                <%#Eval("IsFlagged")%>
            </td>
        </tr>                            
    </tbody>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Now, here's what I'm trying to do. If <%#Eval("IsFlagged")%> returns **anything at all**, i'd like to make all the cells in the table row a certain color.

I've been reading about .contains(), but I haven't found an example that simply asks "if not null, apply a .css style to the rest of the cells of the table row".

Comment: In which exactly moment will you validate your variable, before setting `tr` color? _jQuery_ part is quite simple.

Comment: I went ahead and gave the "special" <td> an id of "findMe". Now, I'd like to select it, then change the previous "Some Text" <tr>s a different color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put together an example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aMR5r/

**Edit:** Your edit makes the code a little simpler, but it's the same principle.

```
$(function(){
    var isFlagged = $('#findMe').text();
    if(isFlagged.length > 0)
    {
        $('#findMe').parent().addClass('yellow');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aMR5r/1/

Comment: Your answer applicable if there is only one cell with specific ID like here it is #findMe. But what if we need to implement to all row or each cells?

Answer (score 1):

First, try to give that specific td a class or someting so you can target it. Then you can check the length of  $('td.yourclassname').html();

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VB.Net then you can use this code..

```
<tr style="background-color:<%# IIF(IsDBNull(Eval("IsFlagged"),"none","yellow") %>">
```

you can apply this logic to TD also.